# How Can I Access/Call My Function with Point in Powershell

Tags: powershell

**My function**

```
function ReplaceR( $myinput ) {
    return $myinput.replace("o","yes")
}

function Go( $myinput ) {
    return $myinput.replace("yes","no")
}

ReplaceR("hello")     # Instead of this
"hello".ReplaceR()    # I want to access my function with "." directly like that, is it possible?

$var1 = ReplaceR("hello")    # Instead of this
$var2 = ReplaceR("$var2")
"hello".ReplaceR().Go()      # Also like that
```

**NOTICE:** This is a simple example i made up to be able to do this process.So, I don't expect an answer like it can be done by adding the replace command to the end of the string. Basically, I want to reach any function I write directly with the help of dots and apply that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to access my function with "." directly like that, is it possible?

In this context, the `.` is [the *member-access operator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#member-access-operator-) - it doesn't really invoke *functions*.

Luckily though, PowerShell's [Extended Type System](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/ets/overview) supports adding synthetic members to almost anything!

In order to attach a new member (in this case a *script method*) to all instances of a given type, use [the `Update-TypeData` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/update-typedata):

```
Update-TypeData -TypeName 'System.String' -MemberType ScriptMethod -MemberName ReplaceR -Value {
  return $this.Replace('o','yes')
}
```

Note: The `$this` special variable refers to the value of the left-hand side operand of the `.` operation.

Now you can call `.ReplaceR()` on any string value:

```
PS ~> "hello".ReplaceR()
hellyes
```

---

If you have multiple methods you want to define for the same target type, consider using [a splatting table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) for the reusable parameter arguments, makes the code slightly more readable:

```
$stringMethodArgs = @{
  TypeName = 'System.String'
  MemberType = 'ScriptMethod'
}

Update-TypeData -MemberName ReplaceR -Value { return $this.Replace('o','yes') } @stringMethodArgs 
Update-TypeData -MemberName Go -Value { return $this.Replace('yes','no') } @stringMethodArgs
```

Comment: Thank you! I think it is only one bug I think, if I applied this my script file, first run is OK, but when I run my script for the second time, it gives an error `Update-TypeData : Error in TypeData "System.String": The member ReplaceR is already present.`

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki You can add `-Force` (or an entry `Force = $true` in the splatting table) if you want to override existing registrations :)

Comment: also thanks to myself for this question :), good question, good answer! :)

Comment: One thing usually leads to the other ^_^